# Adjust when breqn breaks a line in a long equation

Tags: breqn

I'm using the `breqn` package for the first time, and while in one equation I get, using

```
\begin{dmath*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \left(\frac{k}{n} - x\right)^2 \binom{n}{k} x^k (1 - x)^{n - k}  
= \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)x^2 + \frac{1}{n}x - 2x^2 + x^2 
= \frac{1}{n}x(1 - x) 
\leq \frac{1}{4n}\ ,
\end{dmath*}
```

something like that

[image]

I get just in the next line, something like that

```
\begin{dmath*}
\sum_{k \in F}\binom{n}{k}x^k(1 - x)^{n -k} 
\leq \frac{1}{\delta^2}\sum_{k \in F} \left(\frac{k}{n} - x\right)^2
\binom{n}{k}x^k (1 - x)^{n -k}
\leq \frac{1}{\delta^2}\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \left(\frac{k}{n} - x\right)^2
\binom{n}{k}x^k (1- x^k)
\leq\frac{1}{4n\delta^2} \ ,
\end{dmath*}
```

[image]

which is basically the same code but looks way better than the first equation. So I wonder if there's a way to adjust the `dmath` enviroment to make the first equality on the first equation go to the first line, and then break on the second, making my first equation have only three lines.

Comment: You should use `k\hiderel{=}0` and `k\hiderel{\in}F` in order to avoid the bad spacing, but this is a detail. Apparently according to its heuristics, `breqn` decides that making a single line with the first `=` sign yields too long a line and so breaks it. Avoid `breqn` if you want quality output: some more work will be required, but it will be rewarding. Otherwise, be happy with what you get.

Comment: Actually `breqn` worked better for me than `split`, for example, which is a mess, up to this point. It seems that it's just a limitation and that I should work case by case when using it to decide which is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you want to specify where to break the lines, you might as well use `align` here.

Unrelated to the main question, but, it looks like you are trying to add some space before the comma? If that's the case, I'd recommend using `\,` to add some unbreakable thinspace before the comma.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \left(\frac{k}{n} - x\right)^2 \binom{n}{k} x^k (1 - x)^{n - k}  &= \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)x^2 + \frac{1}{n}x - 2x^2 + x^2\\
&= \frac{1}{n}x(1 - x)\\
&\leq \frac{1}{4n}\,,
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Similarly, for your 2nd equation you could use this code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k \in F}\binom{n}{k}x^k(1 - x)^{n -k} &\leq \frac{1}{\delta^2}\sum_{k \in F} \left(\frac{k}{n} - x\right)^2 \binom{n}{k}x^k (1 - x)^{n -k} \\
&\leq \frac{1}{\delta^2}\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \left(\frac{k}{n} - x\right)^2 \binom{n}{k}x^k (1- x^k)\\
&\leq\frac{1}{4n\delta^2},
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it a limitation of `breqn`? Did it decided that the first equality was too long and there was nothing I could do about it?

Comment: I'm no expert on the pros and cons of `breqn`, but one can typeset most equations well, if not better, without needing `breqn`. I suggest reading up on the different ways of aligning equations using amsmath, e.g. `multline`, `align`, `gather` etc. I've loaded the `mathtools` package here which is based on amsmath and includes a number of up-to-date fixes.

Comment: By the way, I can't fully tell but are you trying to add some space between the end of your equation and the comma? If so, I'd recommend writing `\,,`. The command `\,` makes some unbreakable thinspace.

Answer (score 1):

You can force `breqn` to use a specific layout for your equation.  Unfortunately there seems to be a [bug in the package](https://github.com/wspr/breqn/issues/22) because the example fails if I comment in the last line (regardless of which relational symbol I use).  So, yeah, just don't use `breqn`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath*}[layout={L}]
\sum_{k\hiderel{=}0}^{n} \left(\frac{k}{n} - x\right)^2 \binom{n}{k} x^k (1 - x)^{n - k}  
= \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)x^2 + \frac{1}{n}x - 2x^2 + x^2 
= \frac{1}{n}x(1 - x)
%\leq \frac{1}{4n}
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

[image]